# just-audio in Flutter Web not pausing nor stopping

Tags: flutter, just-audio

it seems like I can't pause, stop nor dispose the player in web (chrome,firefox,safari).
It loads and plays allright.
It just keeps playing. Another play adds a layer of sound...
Only a reload of the page stops the cacaphony.
Any Ideas?

```
final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

    Future preload () async {
      await player.setAsset('asset/audio/mysound.mp3');
    }

    Future<void> playSound() async {
      return player.play();
    }

    Future<void> pauseSound() async {
      return player.pause();
    }

    Future<void> stopSound() async {
      return player.stop();
    }

    Future<void> disposeSound() async {
      return player.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Best to create a minimal reproduction project and submit a bug report on GitHub.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. A page reload led to the disconnection of the player. It works as expected.